# What is the C++ way to deal with class templates and their types?

Tags: c++, c++11

I thought I have understood the concept of class templates in C++, but looking at my code I am not so sure anymore. Say I have two classes, a non-template parent and a template as child, like this:

```
class MyParent
{
    std::string m_Name;
    MyParent(std::string Name) : m_Name(Name) { }
    virtual const std::type_info& GetType() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class MyChild : public MyParent
{
    T m_Var;
    const std::type_info& GetType() override
    { return typeid(m_Var); }
};
```

Now in my code I have a container with instances of `MyChild` using a different type, for example:

```
MyParent* p1 = new MyChild<int>("one");
MyParent* p2 = new MyChild<float>("two");
MyParent* p3 = new MyChild<double>("three");
std::vector<MyParent*> v = {p1, p2, p3};
```

So far this is clear, now to where my confusion starts. Say I have a function somewhere that iterates over this vector, then it needs to do some stuff with each element. Some example I just made up (my question is not about the code itself, but how to deal with such a situation):

```
/* ... */
for(auto* p : v)
{
    if(p->GetType() == typeid(int))
    {
        int val = p->m_Var;
        std::list<int> lst = {val, 1, 2, 3};
        if(val >= 0)
            SomeTemplFuncPositive(v * v, lst);  // a template variadic function
        else
            SomeTemplFuncNegative(v * v * -1, lst);
    }
    else if(p->GetType() == typeid(float))
    {
        /* ... now the same block c&p again for float? */
    }
    else if(p->GetType() == typeid(double))
    {
        /* ... and again for double?! */
    }
}
/* ... */
```

In other languages like Python for example I would have this code block only once, but in C++ it seems to me I would need to copy the whole code block again for `float`, and another time for `double`, and so on...

I don't want to blame C++, if that is the way it has to be, then ok. I am just wondering, is this really the correct approach in general when using such a construct in C++?

Comment: You don't have a problem with template but with object. Design with `typeid` is ugly. That why polymorphism exist.

Comment: `if(p->GetType() == typeid(int))` introduces some procedural coding (and thinking). Move all the code from the `if` block inside the class of `*p`. Extend `MyChild<int>` if necessary.

Comment: The fact that your child classes behave differently and that you have to branch on a type implies a flaw in your design. What problem are you really trying to solve? As it stands, this is an XY problem, as in: I've chosen the wrong solution to solve my problem, and now the language is fighting it to the point I'm asking the Internet how to continue. Whenever I get to this point, it's always some backwards choice in solution that led me there and (radically) changing my approach improved things a lot. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: `int val = p->m_Var;` cant work because `p` is a `MyParent*` and `MyParent` does not have a `m_Var` member. You need a typecast: `int val = static_cast<MyChild<int>*>(p)->m_Var;`, which would be better handled by replacing `GetType()` with `dynamic_cast` instead: `if (MyChild<int> *pi = dynamic_cast<MyChild<int>*>(p)) { int val = pi->m_Var; ... } else if (MyChild<float> *pf = dynamic_cast<MyChild<float>*>(p)) { ... } else if (MyChild<double> *pd = dynamic_cast<MyChild<double>*>(p)) { ... }` and so on. Best to rewrite the polymorphism to avoid such `if` checks in the first place like Sam showed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `virtual`-ity needs to be adjusted:

```
class MyParent
{
    std::string m_Name;
    MyParent(std::string Name) : m_Name(Name) { }
    virtual void doSomething()=0;
};

template <class T>
class MyChild : public MyParent
{
    T m_Var;
    void doSomething() override
    {
        T val = this->m_Var;
        std::list<T> lst = {val, 1, 2, 3};
        if (val >= 0)
            SomeTemplFuncPositive(v * v, lst);
        else
            SomeTemplFuncNegative(v * v * -1, lst);
    }
};
```

Now, you invoke `doSomething()` through its base class:

```
for(auto* p : v)
{
    p->doSomething();
}
```

Everything is written exactly once.

Comment: This assumes that `MyChild` has direct access to the `SomeTemplFuncPositive()` and `SomeTemplFuncNegative()` functions. In the original code, the functions were outside of `MyChild`.  If needed, you would just have to pass function pointers into `doSomething()` so it knows what to call.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to cast from Base to Child, your code is most likely wrong (at least in C++). While you're storing pointers to derivatives you should be sure that you won't need public access to their specific members (yet virtual methods still can do so). In this case, list should be declared in derivative and take `T` as template parameter.

Also, you don't need GetType function, you can use `dynamic_cast<DerivativeClass*>(baseClassPtr)`, it returns proper pointer if casting is ok, and nullptr if casting can't be done.